# UserWarning: Interpreter parsed an intent ‘Hi’ which is not defined in the domain

Tags: rasa

The steps I followed to train core is

- rasa train core
- rasa shell

when I am writing hi. I am getting the error as below although intents are defined in domain.yml and in nlu.

```
UserWarning: Interpreter parsed an intent ‘Hi’ which is not defined in the domain.
Please make sure all intents are listed in the domain. and no output is generated
```

**The screenshots**

[nlu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YYV9.png)

[domain.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQj0V.png)

[domain_continued.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoKgw.png)

[stories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pduj5.png)

I am using

- python 3.7.5
- rasa - 1.9.7
- os - linux -ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that the intent `"Hi"` is not in the domain - and it indeed is not in your domain file.

The fact that the message is being classified as the intent `"Hi"` makes me think you may actually be typing `"/hi"`.

The `/` will cause the message to be interpreted as the intent name - rather than the text passed through the model to determine the intent.

Comment: thanks for the reply  but i already have intent in domain file as greet

Comment: i am expecting the reply as hey there! How may i help you"
  -  "Hi, How can I help you!"
  - "Hey, How is it going. How May I help you Today"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Using below commands it is resolved for me.

#Terminal 1

rasa train -vv -dump-stories --force

rasa run actions

#Terminal 2

rasa shell

https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/issues/5066